# Android Activity Not Ending on Back Button Press

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have added the following code to a class I have:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    /*
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("test");
    dialog.setMessage("test 123");
    dialog.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    dialog.create().show();
    */    
    finish();
}
```

I know the method is being called because the alert dialog does display when I press the back button. However the MediaPlayer continues to play when I press back, which takes me to the previous screen.

Why is this? Shouldn't finish() stop the MediaPlayer?

Comment: Usually music is played with a background Service which are not affected by closing activities.

Comment: MediaPlayer is not a part of Activity. `finish()` just finishes Acitivity.

Comment: stop your media player in onPause or onStop

Answer (score 1):

Check for your `MediaPlayer` whether it is playing or not in your `onBackPressed()` event.

Try out as below :

```
   @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
finish();
```

finishes your activity,

you should `stop()` the media player in the activities `onPause()` method (and release it in `onDestroy()`)

Answer (score 0):

OK this is happening because the `MediaPlayer` plays music in a **background Service** so to stop the music you have to add this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(mediaplayer.isPlaying())
          mediaplayer.stop();
    finish();
}
```

Where `mediaplayer` is the instance of `MediaPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    activities.remove(this);
}

public static void finishAll()
{
    for(Activity activity:activities)
       activity.finish();
}
```

or try adding the finish method in onPause() method , that might work aswell...

hope this helps